# Is there a method I could set a key after N seconds?

Tags: python-3.x, redis

I'm using `Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)` and `redis-cli 3.2.100` on `Windows 10` through `pip install redis==2.10.6`

I know there is a way I could set a key expired after N seconds after by using [SETEX](https://redis.io/commands/setex).

```
> SETEX s 10 "hi"
OK
> TTL s  # variable s still alive for 9 seconds
(integer) 9
> GET s
"hi"
> GET s  # ↑ within 10 seconds
"hi"     
> GET s  # ↓ 10 seconds later
(nil)
```

But now I need a way I could set a key after N seconds, for example `SETAF`, and also a way to find a key will born after N seconds, for example `AFTTL`

```
> SETAF s 10 "hi"  # set s="hi" after 10 seconds
OK
> GET s
(nil)
> AFTTL s
(integer) 5
> GET s            # ↑ within 10 seconds
(nil)
> GET s            # ↓ 10 seconds later
"hi"
```

Comment: NO built-in way to do that, you need to implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inbuilt way to do this. Two methods I can suggest are:

1. Set a dummy timer key in redis using `SETEX`, when it expires after N seconds, we set our actual key. 
   **How would we know if the key has expired ?
   That is doable by [subscribing to redis expire events](https://redis.io/topics/notifications?utm_source=tool.lu).**

> EXPIRE generates an expire event when an expire is set to the key, or an expired event every time a positive timeout set on a key results into the key being deleted (see EXPIRE documentation for more info).

2. A simpler way ( where you do not have to do much of the time syncronization work ) is to use a task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), and create a Python method which sets your required key.
   Celery allows decorators and methods like [delay](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay) or [apply_async](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) which would keep the task in queue for N seconds, and execute post that, so that your key would be set in redis after N seconds.

> apply_async(args=None, kwargs=None, task_id=None, producer=None,
>   link=None, link_error=None, shadow=None, **options)[source] Apply
>   tasks asynchronously by sending a message.
>
> Parameters:
>    args (Tuple) – The positional arguments to pass on to the
>   task.
>
> kwargs (Dict) – The keyword arguments to pass on to the task.
>
> countdown (float) – Number of seconds into the future that the task
>   should execute. Defaults to immediate execution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm using the following way :

First define a method to remove the key in redis

r is a `redis.StrictRedis` instance

```
def remove_alarm(code, alarm_last): # alarm_last means how many seconds the key will keep alive
    time.sleep(alarm_last)
    r.srem('alarms', code)
```

In my main program I set a key to redis names alarms and values code and trigger a thread to call remove_alarm

```
r.sadd('alarms', code)  # for code, it a paramater to my function
threading.Thread(target=remove_alarm, args=(code, alarm_last)).start()
```

Although the key "alarms" will exactly keep alive more than `alarm_last` give (starting a thread will take some time), but It is useful for me.